# Spring batch test step scoped bean with @BeforeStep always NPE

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-boot-test

This is step scoped item reader that i want to test, before read list of string should ne init in @BeforeStep

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@StepScope
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeItemReader implements ItemReader<String> {

    @Value("#{jobParameters['date']}")
    private String date;
    private List<String> stringList;

    private final SomeService someService; //its inteface

    @BeforeStep
    public void init() {
            stringList = new LinkedList<>(someService.getList(LocalDate.parse(date)));
    }

    @Override
    public String read() {
        return !stringList.isEmpty() ? stringList.remove(0) : null;
    }
```

and test

```
@ContextConfiguration
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class SomeItemReaderTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomeItemReader someItemReader;

 public StepExecution getStepExecution() {
        StepExecution execution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution();
        execution.getExecutionContext().putString("input.data", "foo,bar,spam");
        return execution;
    }

@Test
void read() {
    assertNotNull(someItemReader.read());//always get NPE here
}
```

}

what did i miss or its not possible to test it?

Comment: For starters you use either `@SpringBootTest` or `@SpringBatchTest` not both, they are mutually exclusive. Also you aren't running anything in a batch fashion so the scoping doesn't apply.

Comment: changed the test - still get NPE on read

Comment: As mentioned you aren't running anything in a batch scope, so no callback will be done, basically the `@BeforeStep` will not be invoked with your current test case.

Comment: Ok, and how to do that?

Comment: You would need to test the actual job that is being run instead of this individual component. The step and job scope are only active within an actual run of a job.

Comment: no, read docs and you will see how to test step scoped components. In most case you dnt need to test job as end to end, and you are able to test single components like ItemReader, ItemProcessor etc...

Comment: You should read the docs. That is for accessing scoped data it won't invoke the callbacks afaik. Which is wha tyou are running into.

Answer (score 1):

The `@BeforeStep` annotated method is executed before the step (in which the reader is involved) is executed. In your test, there is no step running, so you should not be expecting this method to be called.

Moreover, you are injecting a job parameter in the `date` field, but the test does not prepare any job parameter, it rather adds the key/value par `["input.data"="foo,bar,spam"]` in the step execution context, which is not used by the reader.

So to answer your question about how to test a step-scoped bean that is configured with a job parameter, you need to:

1. Create a step execution prepared with your job parameter
2. Declare the reader as a Spring bean so that it gets proxied as needed
3. Autowire the reader in your test class and use `StepScopeTestUtils.doInStepScope` to simulate an execution within the scope of a step

Here is a complete example (based on Spring Batch 5 and JUnit 5):

```
package org.springframework.batch.test;

import java.util.List;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;

import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.IteratorItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class SO75911081 {

    @Autowired
    private MyItemReader itemReader;

    @Test
    void testStepScopedReader() throws Exception {
        // given
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("prefix", "test-")
                .toJobParameters();
        StepExecution stepExecution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution(jobParameters);

        // when
        String item = StepScopeTestUtils.doInStepScope(stepExecution, this.itemReader::read);

        // then
        Assertions.assertEquals("test-foo", item);
    }

    @Configuration
    static class MyConfiguration {

        @Bean
        @StepScope
        public MyItemReader itemReader() {
            return new MyItemReader(List.of("foo"));
        }

        @Bean // not needed when using EnableBatchProcessing
        org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope scope() {
            return new org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope();
        }

    }
    static class MyItemReader extends IteratorItemReader<String> {

        @Value("#{jobParameters['prefix']}")
        private String prefix;

        public MyItemReader(List<String> list) {
            super(list);
        }

        @Override
        public String read() {
            String item = super.read();
            return item != null ? prefix + item : null;
        }
    }
}
```